# Is there any measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\mu$ is concentrated on cantor set of $[0,1]$？

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am dealing with another problem here:

> Is there any nontrivial measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb R$ s.t. $\mu$ is mutually singular with Lebesgue measure $m$ and $\mu(x)=0$ for all $x \in\Bbb R$ ?

It is clear that $m$ is concentrated on $A$ iff $m(A^c)=0.$ This means if $\mu$ and $m$ are mutually singular, we get $\mu$ is concentrated on a set of measure zero.

This question shall be resolved by giving a measure that is concentrated on the Cantor set as the Cantor set has measure zero.

I am stuck here.  Does such a measure exist？

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Cantor "stair-step" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $c : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ to define such a measure. Letting $C \subset [0,1]$ be the Cantor set, for any measurable subset $A \subset \mathbb R$ define $\mu(A) = m(c(A \cap C))$ (where, as you say, $m$ is Lebesgue measure).

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to consider the homeomorphism $f$ from Bernoulli's space $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ to the Cantor set given by
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} x_n/3^n.
$$

Any nonatomic measure on Bernoulli's space pushed forward to the Cantor set would be an example.  Among these one can of course choose Bernoulli's measure!